# Importing EPS to Adobe Photoshop adds stroke around the objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, stroke, eps

I have created an object using Adobe Illustrator and when saving as EPS file and opening it on Photoshop, I see all these white stokes around them:

[image]

if I save it as PNG and open it with a photo viewer I don't see these strokes but as soon as I import it then those strokes are visible in Photoshop. Image mode is set to RGB / 8bit and color settings are set to North America Web/Internet.

I am not sure why this is happening. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it might be an aliasing issue.

Try using **Art Optimized** anti-aliasing, when you export as a PNG

[image: export]

You can also try to disable the anti-aliasing, upon importing your EPS to photoshop, by un-checking the selected box

[image: import]